# *.docker.localhost only works in chrome

Tags: docker, traefik

We are using [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal) with our sites for local development. The problem is that the sites only work in Chrome.  Another user had the same issue [here](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1609).

Here is output of `cat /etc/hosts` inside my container:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.20.0.5  d012518e289d
```

Comment: can you show what's the result of `cat /etc/hosts` on your container?

Comment: Updated the issue with the output.

Comment: try to change `172.20.0.5  d012518e289d` to `172.20.0.5 *.docker.localhost` and run again

Comment: It didn't work after the update.  If I restart the container it goes back to `172.20.0.5  d012518e289d`.

Comment: but does it work if you go to `localhost:PORT` in any browser?

Comment: It doesn't work in any browser.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by adding this to my host file:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.docker.localhost
```

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the point of using Traefik in the first place? It's supposed to do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

As for browser support, the .localhost TLD resolution to 127.0.0.1 works in Firefox as well for me (I test Firefox 56).

Judging from the other comments, I think some people might be running into some kind of server side redirection perhaps because the Host header is not passed. Be sure to have Traefik pass the Host header to the backends. It does this by default though but you can verify it per frontend on the Traefik dashboard page.

To set it explicitly, add the following label to the relevant Docker container in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
labels:
  traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: 'true'
```

For instance, if I set this to 'false' for the Solr container, then the Solr server redirects me to it's container IP instead of serving on the 'nice' domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Once I started using .test instead of .localhost I didn't run into this issue and I didn't have to update my host file.

Comment: Didn't help me at all